# Constructing an expression tree causes InvalidPathException

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees

I'm constructing an expression tree (`Expression<Func<PlainAddress, bool>> predicate`) to pass it to the `IQueryable.Where` function for HNibernate to execute the query. When I pass:

```
 predicate = y => y.Address.City == geoObject.Name;
```

everything works fine. When I pass:

```
var x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(PlainAddress));

Expression<Func<PlainAddress, string>> expression = y => y.Address.City;

predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<PlainAddress, bool>>(
    Expression.Equal(
        Expression.Invoke(expression, x), 
        Expression.Constant(geoObject.Name)), 
        x);
```

I get the following exception

```
Invalid path: 'y.Address.City' 
[.Where(NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryable`1[BPPDicsManager.Domain.Entities.PlainAddress], 
Quote((60ee8287-3f42-426a-8c15-41f62f58623c, ) => (String.op_Equality((y, ) => 
(y.Address.City)60ee8287-3f42-426a-8c15-41f62f58623c, p1))), )]
```

What am I doing wrong? What are the difference between these 2 options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not familiar with NHibernate, but I can try to explain the differences between the two expressions.

1.The major difference is the use of [`Expression.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355170.aspx) in sample # 2, which creates an `InvocatonExpression` that "represents an expression that applies a delegate or lambda expression to a list of argument expressions". This introduces a kind of indirection -  loosely speaking,

Sample # 1 is:

```
y => y.Address.City == geoObject.Name;
```

whereas Sample # 2 is *something* like:

```
x => new Func<PlainAddress, string>(y => y.Address.City).Invoke(x) 
     == geoObject.Name
```

You can get the second sample closer to the first by using [`Expression.Property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341554.aspx) to create the appropriate `MemberExpression`s :

```
var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<PlainAddress, bool>>(
        Expression.Equal(
            Expression.Property(Expression.Property(x, "Address"), "City"),
            Expression.Constant(geoObject.Name)),
            x);
```

This is now closer to:

```
x => x.Address.City == AsStringLiteral(geoObject.Name)
```

(I'm guessing this will be sufficient to get the predicate to work with NHibernate.)

---

2.The other difference of course, is the use of [`Expression.Constant`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb349084.aspx)in sample # 2, which will *eagerly* evaluate the value of `geoObject.Name` and turn that into a *literal* in the expression-tree. You're going to need a lot more work if you want to 'emulate' the hoisting of the `geoObject` variable (or perhaps `this`?) as in sample # 1.

Comment: Sadly this answer received only 4 upvotes in 4 years, but it is a beautiful example of how a hard question like this should be answered.